# How to port the MATLAB libSVM parameters in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, svm, libsvm

In my cross-validation in MATLAB with libSVM I found that these are the best parameters to use:

```
model = svmtrain( labels, training, '-s 0 -t 2 -c 10000 -g 100');
```

Now I want to replicate the classification in C++ with OpenCV.

But I do not understand how to set the C++ parameters to be the same as MATLAB:

Based on [this documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-train) I tried the following:

```
CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF;
//params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10000, 1e-6);
params.Cvalue = 10000;
params.gamma = 100;
CvSVM SVM;
SVM.train(train, labels, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

but I get this error:

```
error: no member named 'Cvalue' in 'CvSVMParams' params.Cvalue = 10000;
```

Last thing, should I uncomment

```
 //params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10000, 1e-6);
```

and try other values or is it not important? 
Because I can't even understand in MATLAB how to set the same parameters.

Comment: it's just [params.C](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/ml/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp#L303) not CValue

Comment: @berak thanks... and about my second question? this line in C: params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10000, 1e-6) has a corresponding in matlab?

Comment: no idea about matlab, sorry. and you only need to set the TermCriteria explicitly, if you want something else than the std values (1000 iter, eps=FLT_MIN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every parameter has an exact equivalent when porting from LibSVM in matlab to OpenCV SVM. The term criteria is one of them. <s>Keep in mind that the SVM of opencv might have some bugs depending on the version you use</s> (not an issue with the latest version).

You should un-comment the line, to have better control of your termination criteria. This line says that the algorithm should end when 10000 iterations are performed. If you use CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, it will stop when a precision less than the specified (for you, its 1e-6) is achieved for each vector. Use both stopping criteria, and it will stop when either of them completes.

Alternatively, could also try using LibSVM for C++, by linking it as a library. This will give you the **exact same** algorithms and functions that you are using in matlab.