# how to use libsvm model generated in matlab for classification in OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, machine-learning, libsvm

I am using libsvm to train the SVM model in matlab. Once I have the trained SVM model I want to use that model in OpenCV for classification of test images. Can someone help me to load SVM model in OpenCV and then use the values generated by the SVM model similarly to that of default people detector in [hog.cpp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgsacm2u88aprf4/hog.cpp?dl=0). Please see the following two functions.

- std::vector cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor::getPeopleDetector48x96()
- std::vector cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor::getPeopleDetector64x128()

**P.S:** I am new to SVM so I am quite confused which values I have to take out in order to classify the test images.

Comment: The loading part is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304569/how-to-port-the-matlab-libsvm-parameters-in-c

Comment: the above question define the equivalent parameter but I want to transfer libsvm model from matlab to opencv